# Scroll bars missing in the saveas window to save a Word document to another folder

Tags: word, save

We are on SharePoint 2013 and I'm trying to simply open a Word document and do a save as to another folder, which has a couple pages worth of folders, and there are no scroll bars showing anymore. So I have to use the Page Down or down arrow to get to the intended folder.

[image]

This article says it might have just occurred in one of the latest Microsoft updates: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8e2b1c0-aa6e-46bf-8a94-1571096f2015/microsoft-office-wordexcel-saveopen-window-not-showing-scrollbar-for-sharepoint-sites?forum=officeitpro

Anybody else see this, or know of a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the latest patches resolves this issue https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d0c3de61-46fb-42b4-a46a-93a0cff2c00d/microsoft-office-wordexcel-saveopen-window-not-showing-scrollbar-for-sharepoint-sites?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/65883)

Comment: dee - thanks for the update, I did see the update fixed the issue!

Comment: @Gaurravs I'm not really sure how much more info could have been added to this answer, when the problem is a genuine bug that's been fixed by a patch from MS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing it to interlinked to us installing the april cu for sp - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8e2b1c0-aa6e-46bf-8a94-1571096f2015/microsoft-office-wordexcel-saveopen-window-not-showing-scrollbar-for-sharepoint-sites?forum=officeitpro&prof=required

Comment: use some important part of link as answer. do not post only links. they may go down